# How to pass passphrase of ssh in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I am discovering the bash scripting. I need to write a bash script to automatically connects my remote server with ssh. I am using MACOSX.

I were able to do with sudo as below

```
echo <root_pass> | sudo -S ls
```

However all my attempts were unsuccessful to pass the passphrase.
I have tried these below already:

```
echo <my_passphrase> | sudo ssh -i /Users/path_to_ssh_public_key/ssh <my_username>@<remote_ip> 

sudo ssh -i /Users/path_to_ssh_public_key/ssh <my_username>@<remote_ip> <<< echo <my_passphrase>
```

The command uses "-i" to get public key from a custom folder

Any help is welcome...

EDIT: I want to fully control the terminal outputs and inputs. I don't want to use sshpass or declare any variables to the shell.

Comment: ssh reads the passphrase from `/dev/tty` rather than `stdin` so `echo ... | ssh ...` would not work here. you can use tools like [tag:expect] (for Tcl), [tag:pexpect] (for Python) or my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) (for shells).

Comment: Or you can use `sshpass`, which was designed for exactly this purpose. Or better yet, stop using passwords and configure ssh key-based authentication.

Comment: I see, thanks for info @larsks . So let me know if I can feed dev/tty in c program or python or even bash script as providing the password.

Comment: @cachius no it is not, actually I have seen it before, but my intention is to take control the terminal fully in a bash script. But the issue you mentioned suggests me to use sshpass or some other extra variable declaring to access ssh.

Comment: BTW, I wonder why people downgrade the question immediately if they do not like it :D rather than asking why he asked this question while there are questions similar

Comment: For your Info After voting one can only change the vote after the post was edited. So good you did 

Comment: Not my downvote, but this type of question is very common, and your question contains no indication that you searched existing questions before asking.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in comments, you can use `sshpass` like so:

```sh
sshpass -p !4u2tryhack ssh username@host.example.com
```

But using `.ssh/config` file is much more convenient.

Sample

```sh
Host fedora
    Hostname 192.168.1.60
    Port 22
    User shm
```

With which I can do

```sh
ssh fedora
```

And since it does not have any key - it uses the default `id_rsa`.

Comment: Thanks @Shakiba Moshiri I will check other login methods too.